# How to add Gitlab user/users to "Allow to Push" in a protected branch using curl?

Tags: curl, post, request, gitlab, branch

I want to add user in "allow to merge" & "allow to push" section in a protected branch using curl
[Settings in Gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2frX.png)

I tried this command, but it replaced all the existing users.

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [private token]" --request POST "http://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/[project id]/protected_branches?name=[branch name]&merge_access_level=40&allowed_to_push%5B%5D%5Buser_id%5D=29&allowed_to_push%5B%5D%5Buser_id%5D=30`

Example:
Before Command: allow to push consists of users with ID 1, 2, 3
After Command: allow to push consists of users with ID 29, 30
Expected result after command: allow to push consists of users with ID 1, 2, 3, 29, 30